# Couchbase spring data with Transactional service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-transactions

I am utilizing Spring Data Couchbase Starter to handle my Couchbase operations, and I need to implement transactions. However, whenever my event document is created by the transactional service, I notice that additional new documents are generated with an ID **_txn:client-record** and data **Binary Document, "\u0000"**. Consequently, I am unable to access my document from other locations, as if it is locked. Here is the code I am using:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class CouchbaseService {

     @Autowired
     EventRepository eventRepository;

    public void  save(Event event){
        log.info("Saving to Couchbase {}",event);
        eventRepository.save(event);
 
    }

}
```

my service :

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class EventProcessingService {

    private final CouchbaseService couchbaseService;

    public EventProcessingService(CouchbaseService couchbaseService) {
        this.couchbaseService = couchbaseService;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void processEvent(Event event) {

// some service code 

        saveEvent(event);
    }

    private void saveEvent(Event event) {
        couchbaseService.save(event);
        log.info("Event Saved : {}",event);
    }
}
```

my event repo :

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Event, String> {
}
```

Maven :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by :

> I am unable to access my document from other locations

When are you trying to access it? (in a query immediately after the save? you may need to use QueryScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)
How are you trying to access it?
What happens when you try to access it?